# get available screen size after considering space used by the menu bar and launcher

Tags: gnu-screen, desktop, size

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.
I know how to get my screen resolution using xrandr or xdpyinfo.  But with these tools I get the maximum available desktop size ....

I have a menu bar at the top that takes some of the available desktop.  I have a launcher on the left that takes some of the available desktop.  How can I find the real available desktop size using a bash script that accounts for the space used by the menu bar and launcher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching I found the xprop command which returns the information I was looking for.

```
available_screen=$(xprop -root | grep -e 'NET_WORKAREA(CARDINAL)') #get available screen dimensions
    available_screen=${available_screen##*=} #strip off beginning text
    current_screen_width=$(echo $available_screen | cut -d ',' -f3 | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//')
    current_screen_height=$(echo $available_screen | cut -d ',' -f4 | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//')
```

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

Since the question specified using `bash`, there is a succinct way to do this:

```
IFS=', =' read -a area < <(xprop -root '_NET_WORKAREA')
```

### Usage

The *x* and *y* coordinates, *width*, and *height* are in the *area* array. You can then use them like so:

```
echo "Top left of usable space: X is ${area[1]} and Y is ${area[2]}"
echo "Width is ${area[3]} and height is ${area[4]}"
```

### Plain Bourne shell

If you're restricted to plain Bourne shell, you can work around the lack of arrays by naming the variables *x*, *y*, *w*, and *h*:

```
xprop -root _NET_WORKAREA > /tmp/workarea$$
IFS=, read x y w h sluff < /tmp/workarea$$
x=${x#*=}
rm /tmp/workarea$$
```

### More information

To read about X11 properties like *_NET_WORKAREA*, please see the [Extended Window Manager Hints](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s03.html) specification at freedesktop.org.

Answer (score 0):

I found that most reliable way to get the width and height is:

```
#!/bin/bash

WINDOW_ID=$(wmctrl -a :ACTIVE: -v 2>&1 | grep -Eo "0x[0-9a-f]{8}")

wmctrl -ir $WINDOW_ID -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz

sleep 1

echo Width is $(wmctrl -lG | grep $WINDOW_ID | awk -v N=5 '{print $N}')
echo Height is $(wmctrl -lG | grep $WINDOW_ID | awk -v N=6 '{print $N}')
wmctrl -ir $WINDOW_ID -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
```

You have to be careful about the value of `sleep`, it can be different.